# Using Linq in domain service in Silverlight

Tags: c#, linq, wcf, silverlight

I kind of feel guilty asking this question because asked a smiliar one before but I did not get a clear answer. I am building a silverlight program and I need to create a Linq query in the domain service (using wcf ria). I need to calculate the sum here is my code

```
int lola = (from c in context.GetTRANSACTIONSQuery()
            where ((c.CHART_ACC == transStudID) && (c.sch_year == 13))
            select c).Sum();

MessageBox.Show(lola.ToString());
```

Between the parenthesis at `Sum()` I get an error that says

> Error 1   Instance argument: cannot convert from 'System.ServiceModel.DomainServices.Client.EntityQuery' to 'System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable'

What am I missing?? I know it is syntax problem because I am new to Linq. Please Thank you!

Comment: What exactly is "GetTRANSACTIONSQuery"?  Can you post its signature at least?

Comment: I think you need to add `.Query` like `.Query.Sum()`.

Comment: this is from the domain service model
`public IQueryable<TRANSACTION> GetTRANSACTIONS()
        {
            return this.ObjectContext.TRANSACTIONS;
        }`

Comment: @KirkWoll yeah tried that same error

Comment: @IMAK, it's syntactically impossible it was actually the *same* error -- `.Query` would return an instance of `IQueryable`, which is a subtype of `IEnumerable` and of course is not an instance of `EntityQuery`, and thus there would be no attempt to convert that type to `IEnumerable`.

Comment: I am unclear if the code you are showing is supposed to be on the client or on the server. You are using `context.GetTRANSACTIONQuery()` , and then provide a definition of the service method, which makes me think you are trying to do this on the client? If so, you're probably best off just making a new service method that you `Invoke` to return the sum you are after. i.e. perform all that Linq on the server directly on the `ObjectContext` and just get the number back.

Answer (score 0):

What are you adding up for Sum()? Can you try:

```
int lola = (from c in context.GetTRANSACTIONSQuery()
            where ((c.CHART_ACC == transStudID) && (c.sch_year == 13))
            select c.PROPERTYTHATYOUWANTTOADDUP).Sum();
```

Or perhaps you wanted to count how many items match your query?

```
int lola = (from c in context.GetTRANSACTIONSQuery()
            where ((c.CHART_ACC == transStudID) && (c.sch_year == 13))
            select c).Count();
```

EDIT:

So since you want to add up the AMOUNT property:

```
decimal lola = (from c in context.GetTRANSACTIONSQuery()
            where ((c.CHART_ACC == transStudID) && (c.sch_year == 13))
            select (decimal)c.AMOUNT).Sum();
```

You can also make sure that c.AMOUNT is never null so you don't run into an error in the future:

```
decimal lola = (from c in context.GetTRANSACTIONSQuery()
            where ((c.CHART_ACC == transStudID) && (c.sch_year == 13) && (c.AMOUNT != null))
            select (decimal)c.AMOUNT).Sum();
```

Comment: I added `c.AMOUNT` then I got this error `Error 1 Cannot implicitly convert type 'decimal?' to 'Global4.Web.TRANSACTION'`

Comment: so I also changed `int lola` to `decimal lola` still same error

Comment: That means c.AMOUNT is a type decimal? and you are casting it to the TRANSACTION model. Is your LINQ different now? Doesn't seem like it would return that error with your code. You have to explicitly cast decimal? to decimal, too. They're not exactly the same thing

Comment: What do you mean if my "LINQ is different"?

Comment: Nope still the same... Like I said I have not done any changes except what I wrote in the beginning of the comments. If you are familiar with TeamViewer you are more then welcome to check it out yourself (That if you want to and you have the time).

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/66623/discussion-between-imak-and-tyress).